# How to continue using cordovaplugin in the newest version of cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, version

I have a project that I begin using phonegap version 2.8, and I'm using three plugins (camera, sqlite and datepicker).
All these plugins are using the old version of phonegap, that means, they are all extending the CordovaPlugin class.
Now I created a new cordova application, and put my www inside this new project, but I can't use my old plugins.
Is there any way to use them? Now my app is using cordova 3.5 and this version don't have the CordovaPlugin class implemented. 
My app is using the android platform.

Thanks for your attention and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Cordova 3.5 only contains the core implementation. camera,sqlite,etc.. plugins are not included by default. You need to manually add them using CLI commands.
For example for adding camera the command is

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

You can go through the cordova CLI commands for 3.5 over [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) for details.

Comment: Yeah, I did it, but I'm using a custom plugin, to show the datepicker dialog when the user taps the date fields. These custom plugins are not compatible with the cordova 3.5...

Comment: Where did you get this custom plugin from? Is this plugin available in the gitHub repository? Can you provide the source of the plugin? wher is the plugin located? How did you install the plugin in the previous cordova version?

Comment: Here's the website where I get the datepicker plugin: https://github.com/ng4e/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DateTimePicker

Comment: @AndersonNunesdaSilva Can you have a look over [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/9/6/Working-with-Plugins-in-PhoneGap-30). It might help you. I see that the plugin is quite old. Don't know whether the datepicker plugin is compatible with phonegap version 3.x and later.

Comment: My project was using phonegap 2.8 and now I need to use the cordova 3.5. I think the best way to do it, its rewritting the parts when I use the plugins, and install the newest plugins using the command line. Thanks for your help, but my time is ending, I need to finish this project until friday.